# Kivy - how do I figure out the path to Widget in .kv file

Tags: python, kivy

in my python code I was able to draw a line in the Widget defined in the .kv file, by using self.canvas.before.

Then, in .kv, I moved the Widget inside the TabbedPanelItem and it does not work correctly anymore.

self.canvas.before is not the correct path, what should I use instead? What is the correct path?

In general, how do I figure out the hierarchy? Those object in .kv file are created by the builder (if my understanding is correct), how do I figure out how to bind the python code to the object created by the builder.
Thank you for any help.

main.py:

```
class SampBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SampBoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas.before:
            self.myline=Line(points=(100,100,400,500), close=False, width=2)
```

main.kv

```
SampBoxLayout:
<SampBoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 0
    spacing: 0
    TabbedPanel:
        do_default_tab: False
        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: "noc_clk"
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                Widget:
                    height: "440dp"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 0.5
                TabbedPanel:
                    do_default_tab: False
                    TabbedPanelItem:
                        text: "Node0"
                        BoxLayout:
                            orientation: "horizontal"
```

Comment: Have you tried using: `os.listdir(...)` or `os.walk(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your app still works correctly even after adding a kv file. The line is being drawn on the canvas of SampBoxLayout, but it is not visible because each widget has an opacity of 1.0 i.e. not transparent. The example below, to show the line drawn, I added `opacity = 0.5` under `TabbedPanel`.

## Hierarchy / Path

[Kv language » Rule context](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#rule-context)

> There are three keywords specific to Kv language:
>
> ***app***: always refers to the instance of your application.
>
> ***root***: refers to the base widget/template in the current rule
>
> ***self***: always refer to the current widget

[Value Expressions, on_property Expressions, ids, and Reserved Keywords](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords)

> ***self***
>
> The keyword self references the “current widget instance”:
>
> ```
> Button:
>     text: 'My state is %s' % self.state
> ```
>
> ***root***
>
> This keyword is available only in rule definitions and represents the
>   root widget of the rule (the first instance of the rule):
>
> ```
> <MyWidget>:
>     custom: 'Hello world'
>     Button:
>         text: root.custom
> ```
>
> ***app***
>
> This keyword always refers to your app instance. It’s equivalent to a
>   call to [kivy.app.App.get_running_app()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.get_running_app) in Python.
>
> ```
> Label:
>     text: app.name
> ```

[Binding Python code to object created in kv file](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code)

## Method 1

- Declare an ObjectProperty at class level and hook it up to the `id` of the object created in kv file. This is the best practice method.

### main.py

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class SampBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    tp = ObjectProperty(None)
```

### main.kv

```
<SampBoxLayout>:
    tp: tp
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 0
    spacing: 0

    TabbedPanel:
        id: tp
        opacity: 0.5
```

## Method 2

- Adding `id` to the object created in kv file and using `self.ids.id-name` or `self.ids['id-name']`

## Best Practice & Speed

> ***Note***
>
> *Although the self.ids method is very concise, it is generally regarded as ‘best practice’ to use the ObjectProperty. This creates a
>   direct reference, provides faster access and is more explicit.*

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.lang import Builder


class SampBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SampBoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas.before:
            self.myline=Line(points=(100, 100, 400, 500), close=False, width=2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    runTouchApp(Builder.load_file('main.kv'))
```

### main.kv

```
SampBoxLayout:
<SampBoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 0
    spacing: 0

    TabbedPanel:
        opacity: 0.5
        do_default_tab: False

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: "noc_clk"
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                Widget:
                    height: "440dp"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 0.5
                TabbedPanel:
                    do_default_tab: False
                    TabbedPanelItem:
                        text: "Node0"
                        BoxLayout:
                            orientation: "horizontal"
```

## Output

[image: Line Drawn]